# What is the best way to share service-using-typescript function that live across components?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got a few TypeScript functions that are used across components. 
They currently live in their own components (which means those functions are repeated across unnecessarily).

Given the fact that these functions do use services ( such as httpClient ), what would be the best course of action so we can bring them into one centralized location and have all of those components tap into them with 0 dups?

Here is what I have done to make it a service based solution

```
1. ng g s javascript-library

2. goto app.module.ts and import it

3. import { JavascriptLibraryService } from './services/javascript-library.service';

4. add it to the providers array in the app.module.ts as well.
  providers: [
    JavascriptLibraryService
  ],

5. add this code into  services/javascript-library.service.ts 

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class JavascriptLibraryService {

  constructor() { }

  blp_test(input) {
    return 'Hello from Library Service';
  }

}


6. goto the component where I want to use it and and import and do dependency injection
( this is my-component.ts )

6a. import { JavascriptLibraryService } from './../../services/javascript-library.service';

6b dependency injection
constructor(
      private javascriptLibraryService: JavascriptLibraryService,
      ) {
  }


7. and finally, as the final step, try to access the function! 

ngOnInit(): void {

    blp_test(); // dead on arrival

}
```

Comment: Well, put them in a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options:

- You can create an abstract class that exposes the methods, and has abstract properties for whichever prop is shared
- Service, as Golu Tiwari mentioned
- Or just place it in /shared/functions/fancy-file.ts, and import the functions.

It really depends on your usecase. :)

EDIT:
Based on the comments you left below, an abstract class seems the best course of action - see https://angular-r8v6ac.stackblitz.io for an example.

This example has an abstract class (TestImpl) that have two shared, abstract variables. What this means, is that the two abstract variables needs to be defined in your components, and have no initial value. All functions that are either protected or public can be used in all components extending this class. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Hey Yusjis, I've updated my answer with the efforts I made to make it happen thru a service but it did not work. I also realized that the functions that I plan to put into that javascript service cannot be javascript, they've got  to be typeScript. I realized that because I cannot do `function blp_test(){}` for example, it has to be blp_test(){}. Just from the get go, function keyword was not allowed. That was my first moment of truth! Is there a trick to make sure the javascript works just like it is.

Comment: you can use function() {}, however this changes the "this" scope. In your question, use this.javascriptLibraryService.blb_test('input'); instead.

Comment: Thanks yusjis. If I were to use the function () {} (knowing that this would result the fact that the "this" scope changes), how will I then be able to call the blp_test? In your reply, you've alresdy specified the this.javascriptLibraryService.blb_test('input'); take care of my example. The one without the function prefixed functions. I'm still curious what's the way out of the option when I do wish to use the function {}.

Comment: If you want to have shared functions, the easiest way would be to use my third answer, where you place your functions in a file, and export them (export function blb_test(input) { ... }) and then import them in your components (import { blb_test } from 'path/to/functions.ts') and use them as you normally would.

Comment: Yusjis, the border line betwen what goes into services and shared functions is so thin, I need glasses to see the diff. :) What would be a better approach for this simple, day-to-day js library functions (such as blpStartWith, blpfEndsWith etc); the shared or the the services? I'm almost sure you'd say go for the shared. But then, the question becomes when should we consider the services ( if at the end of the day, what goes into services, the shared stuff anyway )? See my confusion?

Comment: I don't really think there is a one-size-fits-all answer here - personally I have utility stuff that doesnt need access to any app context in a shared functions file, while I have stuff that needs access to the app context & have some shared state in a service.

Comment: Thank you. Is there an `include` like functionality in typescript to the sense that you can take out any function (or group of functions or a meaningful section of code ) from the current whatever.component.ts file and then paste it in say shared.ts and then include that section by simply pointing to that file. Is there such a thing? What's the closest thing to this functionality? I've got a about 20 functions that's got this.x, this.y in them (where x and y are either template variables,  or local functions ) and they are to be used in component-y.ts & component-z.ts. Services fail the `this`

Comment: Basically, if the blp_test happened to have `this.x` or `this.y`, where x and y is defined in the component class, this services approach would fall flat here cause the `this` is not recognized in that shared file. I hate the duplicate code and I cannot figure this out.

Comment: updated my answer with how to use an abstract class - seems to be the best solution for your case :)

Comment: Thank you Yusjis, but the link you posted ( https://angular-r8v6ac.stackblitz.io/ ) does not have code. All it has the message `Hello Angular 5! Start editing to see some magic happen :)`

Answer (score 1):

Make Angular service for such functions and import it to app module's providers, now you're free to use these functions across all components.

Comment: Hi Golu, I wanted to choose this approach and did the following basics but the test function I wrote is not recognized in the component. Here are the steps 1) ng g s that-new-service   2) import that new service in the app.module.js and make sure I provide thru the providers-array 3) goto the component, import that new service and do the dependency injection thru the constructor 4) test the test function in ngOnInit but it is dead on arrival. What could be wrong in this sequence? I've updated the steps in my original post.

Comment: Can you please provide the error you are getting and also let me know is there any additional module is used while you are generating your angular service other than app module.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options you might consider:

---

Creating common module with all shared functions, classes, constants etc.

```
// common/DateHelper.ts
export default class DateHelper {
  static someHelperFunction(date) {...}
  static otherHelperFunction() {...}
}
```

And then import it in your component like so:

```
import DateHelper from 'common/DateHelper';
```

To enable importing using absolute paths you will need some `Typescript compiler options`. You can find more in [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/10/07/absolute-paths-javascript/) blog post.

---

Just create bunch of common angular services like so:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
}
```

---

If you are using typescript for backend and you know you will be reusing the same pieces of code in backend and frontend you might even consider creating common module with its own package.json. Then, it will be possible to reuse the same pieces of code between multiple microservices.